# Adding subtitle in video using php-mpeg

Tags: php, laravel-5, ffmpeg-php

I am using [PHP-FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) (a php wrapper for FFMpeg exacutable library) for making a very basic video editor. 
I am facing two issues right now. Below are description of those issues:

1.) Currently, I am adding subtitles to the video by using code below:

```
shell_exec('ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i uploads\abc.mp4 -i uploads\abc.srt -scodec mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng uploads\converted\exportx1.mp4');
```

Now, Its kinda my own custom code for adding subtitles in the video. I want to find a way (as I am working with Laravel Framework) to implement this functionality through package mentioned above (if anyone have enough experience with this package).

There is an option in the package that provides us with the facility of adding custom filters. 
I am trying with this code using that package:

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(array(
        'ffmpeg.binaries'  => 'ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe',
        'ffprobe.binaries' => 'ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe',
        'timeout'          => 3600,
        'ffmpeg.threads'   => 2,
    ));
    $video = $ffmpeg->open('uploads\abc.mp4');

    $video
        ->filters()
        ->custom('-i uploads\abc.srt -scodec mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng')

$video
        ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\WebM(), 'uploads\converted\exportx1.webm')
```

But its giving me [this](http://www.screencast.com/t/RhbxW8IPM8) error.

2.) My second issue is that the shell_exec code (the first one) is adding the subtitles but I have to select them manually. I want them to be selected by default so that I don't have to perform another operation.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that your current problem is that you are unable to select a _default_ subtitle and are having to manually select it when playing the video?

Comment: my main issue is that how can i add subtitle through library PHP-FFMpeg.

Comment: have you followed the instructions provided on the GitHub page for the package? If so which part are you having problems with?

Comment: Please move the code from your comment to an edit on your question - it is incomprehensible in it's current form.

Comment: @KallumTanton I have update the question. Please review it